# VBA - Select Value from IE Dropdown list

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

Trying to select the `Value="localecsv"` option from a drop-down list on IE with VBA. I'm not sure on the process of this

[image]

```
Dim DropOptions As Object
Set DropOptions = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("select")

For Each DropOptions In DropOptions
    If DropOptions.Value = "localecsv" Then
        DropOptions.Selected = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: You can use `objIE.document.getElementById("xf")` instead of getElementByTagName.

Comment: Also, you can directly set the value using `objIE.document.getElementById("xf").Value = "localecsv"`

Comment: objIE.document.querySelector("[value=localecsv]").Selected = True

Comment: You could use the following code to select the value: ` For Each objOption In IE.Document.getElementById("xf").Options With objOption If .Value = "localecsv" Then .Selected = True Else .Selected = False End If End With Next`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to select the item and set it's value in VBA.

```vb
While objIE.ReadyState <> 4 Or ie.Busy: DoEvents: Wend

Dim ddXf As Object
Set ddXf = objIE.document.getElementById("xf")
ddXf.Value = "localecsv"
```